# Openlayers 3 - Equivalent of OpenLayers.Class

Tags: openlayers

I've been playing around with the OpenLayers 3 library, I've previously used OpenLayers 2 and created custom classes like so:

```
OpenLayers.CustomClass = OpenLayers.Class({

    property: value,

    function: function() {
        ...
    },

    CLASS_NAME: 'OpenLayers.CustomClass'

});
```

Then I can instantiate it like so:

```
var customClass = new OpenLayers.CustomClass();
```

However so far I can't see how to recreate this functionality in OpenLayers 3. Is this because it doesn't exist? I can see that there is an ol.Object class but I haven't been able to extend this abstract class with one of my own in a similar fashion.

It's quite likely what I'm trying to do is not necessary in OpenLayers 3 and that a different approach is required.

****UPDATE:****

I followed the link in ymirsson's comment and think I may have an approach that works. Essentially I wanted to create my own class that extended the ol.Object class. The following appears to do this:

```
function CustomClass() {

    ol.Object.call(this)
}

CustomClass.protoype = Object.create(ol.Object.prototype);
```

Now I can set and register listeners for properties on the CustomClass like so:

```
var customClass = new CustomClass();
CustomClass.on('change:property', function(event) {
    alert('Property changed');
});
customClass.set('property', 'testString');
```

However I'm not sure if this is the best approach...

Comment: That Constructor [seems to be gone](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/Class-js.html#OpenLayers.Class), but maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767050/how-do-i-initialize-the-ol-map-using-my-own-class-mymap-using-inheritance-in) is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Openlayers 3 is build with the Google Closure Library so if you wanna do inheritance you got 2 options:

1. Option:

   ```
   my.CustomVectorLayer = function(settings){
      ...
      ol.layer.Vector.call(this, settings);
   };
   ol.inherits(my.CustomVectorLayer, ol.layer.Vector);

   var myLayer = new my.CustomVectorLayer(settings);
   ```

After that you can modifiy your class object and append further methods via prototype style (means my.CustomVectorLayer.prototype.myCustomFn = function().. }. This approach is some case a bit vulnerable and is better for use when you also use the closure compiler for compiling your code together with ol3.

2. Option:

   ```
   var getCustomVectorLayer = function(settings){
       var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector(settings);
       vectorLayer.myCustomFn = function(...);
       return vectorLayer;
   };

   var myLayer = getCustomVectorLayer(settings);
   ```

The second approach is maybe a bit more stable and uses a kind of constructor function.

I hope that helps you regarding your question.

Comment: Thanks for this, I guess I need to read up on the Google Closure Library to get a better understanding of how that works.

Comment: Is there any ES6 version of this, which actually using class?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found a reasonable approach to solve my initial problem. I shall post it here incase it helps anyone else.

In this example lets say we want a class that contains the map object for management purposes we could do something like:

```
function MapManager() {

    /* Create an <ol.Object> using MapManager
    as the target. This will give MapManager
    all of the properties/functions from <ol.Object>
    and allow us to add our own through the prototype */
    ol.Object.call(this);
}

//Inherit all of <ol.Object> attributes
ol.inherits(MapManager, ol.Object);

//Add class specific functions/attributes
MapManager.prototype.getMap = function() {
    console.log(this.constructor.name + ': Getting map...');
    return this.get('map');
};

MapManager.prototype.setMap = function(map) {
    console.log(this.constructor.name + ': Setting map...');
    this.set('map', map);
};
```

This wraps the get/set functionality of ol.Object (such as being able to watch for changes in properties) in our own get/set methods incase we want to perform logic on the values before getting/setting them.

Then we can do something like this:

```
var mapManager = new MapManager();
mapManager.on('change:map', function(event) {
    alert('Map value changed');
});
mapManager.setMap(map);

var map = mapManager.getMap();
```